# How do I change the color and background color of a div in jquery with radio button clicked?

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
<body>
<input type="radio" id="txtElement3" />Voorgrond<br />
<input type="radio" id="txtElement2" />Achtergrond<br />
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop1">Stel kleur in</button>
<div id="divResult">Voorbeeld tekst</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnKnop1").on('click', function () {
            if ($('#txtElement3').is(':checked')) {
                var txtElement = $('#txtElement').val()
                $('#divResult').css('color', txtElement)
            } if ($('txtelement2').is(':checked')) {
                var txtElement = $('#txtElement').val()
                $('#divResult').css('background-color', txtElement)
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```

I tried this, at first it did work, now it doesn't work anymore.
How to change the div color, and background color when radio button is checked and on button click?

Comment: You've missed the `#` in front of `txtelement2` selector

Answer (score 1):

Changes I did:

- added a name to the radio buttons so if you click one, the other is deactivated
- fixed the CSS selectors
- overriden the result to the search

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="col" id="txtElement3" />Voorgrond<br />
<input type="radio" name="col" id="txtElement2" />Achtergrond<br />
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop1">Stel kleur in</button>
<div id="divResult">Voorbeeld tekst</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnKnop1").on('click', function () {
            if ($('#txtElement3').is(':checked')) {
                var txtElement = $('#txtElement').val()
                $('#divResult').css('color', txtElement).css('background-color', 'white');
            } if ($('#txtElement2').is(':checked')) {
                var txtElement = $('#txtElement').val()
                $('#divResult').css('background-color', txtElement).css('color', 'black');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: the background color needs to be set through the input field, so if i type in the input field #A478BE, the color gets added to the div.

Comment: also the first one (voorgrond) is color, and the second one (achtergrond) is background-color.

Comment: @user22934804 edited my answer accordingly. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct solution.

Comment: I got banned from asking questions, how do i fix it?

Comment: @user22934804 you need to edit your questions in order to lift the ban. Here's an article about that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 1):

For the radio button with label Achtergrond has id `txtElement2` but in the code you wrote `txtelement2` and also there is no `#` before it.

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <input type="radio" id="txtElement3" name="txtElement" />Voorgrond<br />
    <input type="radio" id="txtElement2" name="txtElement" />Achtergrond<br />
    <input type="text" id="txtElement">
    <button id="btnKnop1">Stel kleur in</button>
    <div id="divResult">Voorbeeld tekst</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnKnop1").on('click', function() {
                var txtElement = $('#txtElement').val();
                if ($('#txtElement3').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#divResult').css('color', txtElement).css('background-color', 'inherit');
                }
                if ($('#txtElement2').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#divResult').css('background-color', txtElement).css('color', 'inherit');
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```